# Are the Johnson graphs Hamiltonian?

Tags: graph-theory

Does anyone know if the Johnson graphs are Hamiltonian? I would appreciate any references pertaining to problem.

Comment: In fact, Johnson graphs are Hamilton-connected: http://amc-journal.eu/index.php/amc/article/view/291

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorem 3.20 of http://www.science.uva.nl/onderwijs/thesis/centraal/files/f1182505387.pdf
seems to imply that the answer is yes.